# Unable to install groovy plugin in eclipse luna offline mode since firewall is blocking

Tags: eclipse, groovy, plugins, zip, installation

Unable to install groovy plugin in eclipse luna marketplace since system blocked with firewall. Is there any to install it in offline mode through local archive if it is where can get the zip for groovy plugin

Comment: Note that Eclipse Luna is 6 years and 11 releases old, you should really try to run something more modern. Current versions of plug-ins for Eclipse may not run on such an old version.

Answer (score 0):

You can get an offline zip here: https://dist.springsource.org/release/GRECLIPSE/2.9.2/e4.4/org.codehaus.groovy-2.9.2.xx-201801052226-e44-RELEASE-updatesite.zip

Links are at the bottom of the page: https://github.com/groovy/groovy-eclipse/wiki/2.9.2-Release-Notes

2.9.2 is the last version to support Luna.